# Designing the User Interface for an android app

Tags: android

Recently I've been building an app using eclipse and the android xml editor for the layout/visual design of the app. I finished most of the code for the app and now i want to design the interface so its more usable and looks much better than standard buttons. Does anyone know of any tutorials or software or really any way to do this. All i could think of was use photoshop to create icons for the button and such but maybe there is a better way to go about designing the user interface of an app than using images from photoshop?
Hope I explained that well enough, Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: posting DDMS screenshots of your interface would be helpful for specific suggestions, otherwise see my answer for general advice

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried Gimp, Photoshop CS2, Draw Plus. ALl these programs are extremely frustrating when trying to do pixel by pixel work on icons that are 32x32 pixels. They either colour the wrong pixel or don't color it in at all. I tried Microsoft paint, but it doesn't seem to have have support for transparency.

Comment: I'm late but if anyone is using Jetpack Compose, check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uidesigns.withsourcecode . There are many UI designs along with code and it's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general Android UI design tips:

[Filthy Rich Android Clients - Romain Guy](http://www.devoxx.com/download/attachments/1705921/D8_C_10_09_04.pdf)

[Google I/O 2010 - Android UI design patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0)

[Android UI Design Tips - Slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips)

Comment: Those are really great tips thank you, but how would one go about actually designing those amazing looking interfaces? For instance the Slideshow you linked to, the twitter client it shows has a bar across the top with the twitter logo and then three buttons inside the banner. How would you design that? In photoshop? Like is that banner one big blue image with buttons on top of it or what? Sorry if this isn't clear

Comment: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0wYSnCBkoR6NzJiNTFjM2YtOTQxOC00ZjMzLTkxMjQtM2Q3ZjA4ZjY5NWYw&hl=en&pli=1

The google I/O 2010 app also has this in its source code, I couldn't find it for some reason.

But honestly, if you want to make better UI's in the near future, (Android 3.x will be on phones!) you should learn from some of the new Android 3.0 API samples. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

(LOOK FOR NEW THINGS THAT INTEREST YOU)